# how to configure server to look in to .xphp extention files for php code

Tags: php, parsing, configuration, php-ini

In my project I want to store all new/specific code into files with xphp extension but I want server to parse those file as .php.
Can we configure this. If yes how?

I am using Apache server with php 5.6.3, with access to server configurations.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please take a look at this , [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), what's your server ? what's your php version ? do you have an access to your server configurations files or not ?

Comment: Thanks for the guide link, I will make sure next time to follow.
I am using Apache server with php 5.6.3, Yes I have access to server configuration.
Thanks again for helpful answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in apache2 you can add multiple handlers as follows:

within your `.conf` file which is often located in `/etc/apache/sites-available/` in linux/ubuntu , add this line

```
AddType: application/xhttpd-php .xphp
```

this will only take effect on the virtual host which you are adding this line to,

if you want your changes take effect on all your hosts, add this line to your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

if you don't have an access to you server configurations files :

you can add this line to your `.htaccess` file :

```
Addhandler application/x-httpd-php .html .php .xphp
```

don't forget to restart your apache2 after changing the conf files

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```